# append thead inside of table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I seem to be mis-understanding something about jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function while trying to create an HTML `table` dynamically.

I have a `div` that will serve as the container:

```
<div id="tablecontainer"></div>
```

In my JavaScript I seem to be correctly placing an empty `table` inside my container div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tableContainer = $('#tablecontainer'),
        $table = $tableContainer.append('<table></table>'),
        $thead = $table.append('<thead></thead>');
});
```

But, when I attempt the same approach in placing a `thead` tag inside the `table` it seems to be placing it outside of the table, **rather than nested inside the table**.

Here is what it looks like in Chrome's dev-tools:

[image: picture of thead tag not being nested inside table tag]

And here is what I was expecting:

```
<div id="tablecontainer">
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead
    </table>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/dabigecopo/edit?html,output) is a jsbin.

Any idea on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` doesn't return the element you've just appended, so:

```
$table = $tableContainer.append('<table></table>')
```

`$table` is actually pointing to `$tableContainer` still.

There are several solutions but you can use `$tableContainer.find('table')` to get the proper reference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `$tableContainer` and `$table` are same in this case. Because `append()` method returns the element itself. You can use `find()` like following.

```
var $tableContainer = $('#tablecontainer'),
    $table = $tableContainer.append('<table></table>'),
    $thead = $table.find('table').append('<thead></thead>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytable = $('<table/>', {
    class: 'print_table '
  }).append(
          $('<thead/>'),
          $('<tfoot/>'),
          $('<tbody/>')
          );
```

// Well and to add something for example in **thead**

```
$("thead", mytable).append(TitleCell);
```

Comment: Firstly, what are you trying to achieve here? Please do mention you problem/question properly.